# Change circle colour every 5 seconds

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpainter

I try to create a green circle which every 5 seconds disappears.

Actually, I have the green circle created with the `QPainter` method. I tried `QTimer` and others methods but I can't find the good solution.

I overrided the paintEvent function like this :

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    Qt::BrushStyle style = Qt::SolidPattern;
    QBrush brush(Qt::green, style);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setBrush(brush);
    painter.drawEllipse(525, 5, 50, 50);
}
```

```
MainWindow::MainWindow() : QWidget()
{
    QTimer *ledtimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(ledtimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(run_led()));
    ledtimer->start(5000);
}
```

I tried to do something like this, but when i'm using run_led, it tells that painter is already removed (i tried in MainWindow class).

I understand the signal function and the timer, I used it in another files, so some tips would be appreciated. Am I supposed to use timers to make circles wink ?

Comment: And where is run_led?

Comment: It's a useless function, just for test. I copy paste the same code as paintEvent

Comment: Problem is `MainWindow::paintEvent`! You should never do that for sub-classes of `QMainWindow`!

Comment: I should make it apart ?

Comment: If `run_led` is a useless function, what is the timer doing here in the example as it is never used for something useful. You probably want to call `update` periodically and switch the state of your window (green circle visible/hidden).

Comment: This is exactly what I missed. The update function is what I was looking for. 

It works ! thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a flag boolean that changes every 5 seconds and in paint use a brush as global variable

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    ....
    QBrush brush(myBrush, style);
    ...
}

and in slot (run_led)

void MainWindow::run_led()
{
    c != true;
    if(c)
    {
        myBrush=Qt::green;
    }
    else
    {
        myBrush=Qt::gray;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "c" mean ?

Comment: I just tried your example. The boolean is changing value and the color too but not the circle. It looks like the function doesn't execute the paintevent function...

Comment: this example is working, you have to call the update function to make it modifying the window.
Like this : 
`connect(ledtimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(run_led()));
connect(ledtimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));`

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming your `MainWindow`inherits `QMainWindow`**

---

`MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` is a function that tells the systems to render your window.
So I let you guess what goes wrong when you override it like this.

But you can put the drawing in a `QWidget` made for this : `QGraphicsView` which displays the content of `QGraphicsScene` .

You should create a `slot` to do what you want, like this :

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_led_timer_timeout(){

/*
 Do stuff the the QGraphicsScene or QGraphicsView
*/

}
```

And then connect the correct `signal` of your `QTimer` to it :

```cpp
connect(ledtimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::on_led_timer_timeout);
```

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
class QSimpleLed : public QWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(QColor color READ color WRITE setColor)
public:
   using QWidget::QWidget;

   void setColor(const QColor& c) {
      if (m_color != m) {
          m_color = m;
          update();
      } 
   }

   QColor color() const;

   void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override;

private:
   QColor m_color;
}
```

Implementation above should be obvious.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app{argc, argv};

    QSimpleLed led;
    auto animation = new QPropertyAnimation(&led, "color");
    animation->setStartValue(Qt::red);
    animation->setEndValue(Qt::green);
    animation->setLoopCount(-1);
    animation->setDuration(5000);
    animation->start();

    led.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: It is public according to documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariantanimation.html#startValue-prop